# How to format json from the MVC 5 Controller like this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, jsonresult

I have this JSON format

```
[
    {
    info: {
        name: "Quiz no 1",
        main: "this is description of quiz no 1",
        results: "this is the result or remarks after the quiz."
    },
    question: {
        q: "1 + 1 is?",
        a: {
            option: "one",
            correct: false
        }
    }
},
{
    info: {
        name: "Quiz no 1",
        main: "this is description of quiz no 1",
        results: "this is the result or remarks after the quiz."
    },
    question: {
        q: "1 + 1 is?",
        a: {
            option: "two",
            correct: true
        }
    }
},
{
    info: {
        name: "Quiz no 1",
        main: "this is description of quiz no 1",
        results: "this is the result or remarks after the quiz."
    },
    question: {
        q: "1 + 1 is?",
        a: {
            option: "three",
            correct: false
        }
    }
},
{
    info: {
        name: "Quiz no 1",
        main: "this is description of quiz no 1",
        results: "this is the result or remarks after the quiz."
    },
    question: {
        q: "1 + 1 is?",
        a: {
            option: "four",
            correct: false
        }
    }
}
]
```

this is the JSONRESULT from my controller here is the code i used

```
  public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var quizJSON = from a in db.infoQuestions
                       join b in db.QuestionAnswers1
                       on a.questionAnswerID equals b.questionAnswerID
                       select new
                       {
                           info = new
                           {
                               name = a.info.name,
                               main = a.info.main,
                               results = a.info.result
                           },
                           question = new
                           {
                               q = b.Question.question1,
                               a = new
                               {
                                   option = b.Answer.option,
                                   correct = b.Answer.correct
                               }
                           }
                       };
        return Json(quizJSON, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the problem is the json format i need is something like this

```
"info": {
    "name":    "Test Your Knowledge!!",
    "main":    "<p>Think you're smart enough to be on Jeopardy? Find out with this super crazy knowledge quiz!</p>",
    "results": "<h5>Learn More</h5><p>Etiam scelerisque, nunc ac egestas consequat, odio nibh euismod nulla, eget auctor orci nibh vel nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris vel neque sit amet nunc gravida congue sed sit amet purus.</p>"
},
"questions": [
    { 
        "q": "What number is the letter A in the English alphabet?",
        "a": [
            {"option": "8",      "correct": false},
            {"option": "14",     "correct": false},
            {"option": "1",      "correct": true},
            {"option": "23",     "correct": false} 
        ]
    },
    { 
        "q": "Which of the following best represents your preferred breakfast?",
        "a": [
            {"option": "Bacon and eggs",               "correct": false},
            {"option": "Fruit, oatmeal, and yogurt",   "correct": true},
            {"option": "Leftover pizza",               "correct": false},
            {"option": "Eggs, fruit, toast, and milk", "correct": true}
        ]
    },
    { 
        "q": "Where are you right now? Select ALL that apply.",
        "a": [
            {"option": "Planet Earth",           "correct": true},
            {"option": "Pluto",                  "correct": false},
            {"option": "At a computing device",  "correct": true},
            {"option": "The Milky Way",          "correct": true} 
        ]
    },
    { 
        "q": "How many inches of rain does Michigan get on average per year?",
        "a": [
            {"option": "149",    "correct": false},
            {"option": "32",     "correct": true},
            {"option": "3",      "correct": false},
            {"option": "1291",   "correct": false} 
        ]
    },
    { 
        "q": "Is Earth bigger than a basketball?",
        "a": [
            {"option": "Yes",    "correct": true},
            {"option": "No",     "correct": false}
        ]
    } 
]
```

can i generate it using the controller or i have to get data pieces by pieces and combine it . What is the best solution to my problem. Advance thanks Sir and Ma'am

Comment: use a ViewModel class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view model with the following structure:

```
public class Info
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string results { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public string option { get; set; }
    public bool correct { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string q { get; set; }
    public List<A> a { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Info info { get; set; }
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
}
```

Rename the classes as you see fit.
I use the [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) code generation tool it.

Your controller action code would become:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var quizJSON = from a in db.infoQuestions
                       join b in db.QuestionAnswers1
                       on a.questionAnswerID equals b.questionAnswerID
                       select new 
                       {
                           info = new Info
                           {
                               name = a.info.name,
                               main = a.info.main,
                               results = a.info.result
                           },
                           questions = new List<Question>() { new Question
                           {
                               q = b.Question.question1,
                               a = new List<A> () { new A
                                {
                                   option = b.Answer.option,
                                   correct = b.Answer.correct
                                }
                              }
                           }
                          }
                       };
        return Json(quizJSON, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your fast respond but the jsonresult is still not the same format i need

Comment: `[  
{
info: {
name: "Quiz no 1",
main: "this is description of quiz no 1",
results: "this is the result or remarks after the quiz."
},
questions: [
{
q: "1 + 1 is?",
a: [
{
option: "one",
correct: false
}
]
}
]
}]`

Comment: it is possible to list all question under the info and all answer under the question like the one in the example that i gave

Comment: @eagoregordy Give me a few mins, will check. Without the entity framework I will just dummy up some data.

Comment: @eagoregordy questions and info are at the same level in the json mind, not below in the example given.

Comment: sorry but it didn't work. I'm using s[SlickQuiz](https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz) plugin my problem is how to convert my CMS data to the json format that the plugin needs. Maybe my database relation is the problem.

Comment: can you gave me some ideas? to fix it

Comment: @eagoregordy I think it might be. I would break it down into chunks. Start with the structure I have given for the classes and hardcode questions in. Then look at replacing it one at a time with actual data from your CMS. That way you will have a working front end and you will see which parts break it. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try. Can you help me build the database the structure that i will need for this. I'm not good in database structuring please help -_-

Comment: Thank you atlast i did it hahahhahaha @hutchonoid your answer is correc as I suspected my database data is the problem thank you for your time :D Now my only problem is the data is not working in the SlickQuiz

Comment: Last question 
`Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 
`
in the line ` correct = b.Answer.correct`

Comment: @eagoregordy Nice one, excellent. Now what I would do is, take the rendered json and create a simple example on jsfiddle and post another question. If it is isolated to a simple example people will answer quicker. :D Good luck.

Comment: @eagoregordy Change it to `correct = b.Answer.correct.GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: ** Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)** you just have to put question mark in bool in your viewmodel :D

Comment: @eagoregordy The above should do or you could change the correct property on A class to bool? `public class A
{
    public string option { get; set; }
    public bool? correct { get; set; }
}`

Comment: i have encountered some problem with my project. The problem is if i put a primary key on my QuestionAnswer Table the JSONRESULT changed. I need to have some primary key there because my entity framework wont have insert and delete functionality because it doesn't have a primary key please help. :(

Comment: @eagore-gordy unfortunately I'm not at a pc. I would create a new question with json output before & after someone should answer quicker.

Comment: Thank you @hutchonoid I can't ask a question now because i reached the limit. Maybe if you are in a pc some other time just inform me thank you for all of your help. :D